# How to fetch data from first row to a particular row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables table 1 (log_audit table) table 2  is (final_log table)

table 1 data looks like below

[image]

table 2 data looks like below

[image]

Here user "D" actual resolver of the customer ticket. so we want the data from ticket start time (i.e 2020-05-01 10:00:00) to till first assigned to the user "D" (here the ticket first assigned to "D" on "2020-05-01 10:20:00")

The expected output should be like from 1st row to till 4th row

[image]

please help me on this.

Comment: How do you know who the resolver is?

Comment: table 2 (final_log table) is contains the ticket # and who resolved it. This table contains one record for each ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `left join` and window functions:

```
select la.*
from (select la.*,
             min(case when fl.actual_user is not null then la.start_time end) over (partition by la.ticket_id) as actual_user_start_time
      from log_audit la left join
           final_log fl
           on fl.actual_user = t.user
     ) la
where start_time <= actual_user_start_time;
```

Comment: This is giving only one record. First record

Comment: @kalyan4uonly . . . I fixed the answer.  The `case` used the wrong table for identifying which date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach you can try. However, the syntax might be a bit different for your database -

```
SELECT t1.ticket_no,
       t1.user,
       MIN(t1.start_time),
       MIN(t1.end_time)
   FROM log_audit t1
   LEFT JOIN final_log t2
   ON t2.ticket_no = t1.ticket_no
   GROUP BY t1.ticket_no, t1.user
   ORDER BY t1.user ASC
```

Comment: what if user A work on the ticket in multiple intervals (he might have multiple records) if that is the case then we will miss the remaining records of user A